# help to explain scheduled script

Tags: shell

Purpose of the script :

1.This script will delete Files older than 4 months.
2.Files older than 3 days will be compressed.

A script has been written such as :

```
 #!/bin/bash

 exec >> /dir5/dir6/cleanup-logfiles.log 2>&1

 # customer list job
 cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/tmp
 find -type f -mtime +120 -exec rm -v '{}' \;
 find -type f -mtime +3 -name '*.csv' -exec gzip -v '{}' \;
```

Can anyone please explain usage of both the above commands (and how do they serve the purpose ?

And this script has been placed at /etc/. what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` without a command parameter redirects all output (stdout + stderr [`2>&1`]) from the current shell (i.e. this script) to /dir5/dir6/cleanup-logfiles.log

`cd` changes directory ;)

the `find` commands will find all files (`-type f`) whose modified time (`-mtime`) is older than 120, respectively 3 days and: delete them (`-exec rm -v '{}' \;`) or gzip them (`-exec gzip -v '{}' \;`). gzipping only happens when the file has a csv extension (`-name '*.csv'`)

`{}` is a placeholder for the currently found file

the script is probably run through cron (`/etc/cron.{d,daily,hourly,weekly,monthly}` or `/etc/crontab`)